# Pixel data read with glReadPixels() from texture bent

Tags: opengl, graphics, textures

I'm working on a library where part of the functionality involves reading the texture data and save it to an image file (i.e. .png). I'm running into a problem where I cannot seem to figure out the cause.

The problem is that part of the output image is bent. All the code doing right now is "attach" the input image's pixel data to a texture, and read it right back out. Specifically, I'm working with a 256x256 image with RGBA8 pixel format.

Here's the input image:

[image: input image]

And here's the output image. You can see how it's bent half way down the height:

[image: input image]

The code is all very straight. For attaching the input image to the texture:

```
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);

unsigned int textureID = 0;
glGenTextures(1, &textureID);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8 /** internalFormat */, image->Width(), image->Height(), 0 /** border */,
                 GL_RGBA /** format */, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, reinterpret_cast<const void*>(image->Buffer()->Data()));
```

And the code for reading it back out (directly from the default frame buffer):

```
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
glReadPixels(x, y, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

The vertex positions and UV indices basically cover the entire viewport (a square), so I don't think the problem is there.

Maybe there's something super obvious that I'm just not seeing. Hope some kind and brilliant souls can shed some light here.

Thanks in advance!

Oh, I should mention that I'm working with OpenGL Core Profile version 3.3.

Comment: The problem is not related to the loading of the texture. One of the y components texture coordinates is wrong.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thank you! You are correct. Turns out there was a mistake in the index buffer.